# Do I have to run installutil.exe if I make a change to a Windows Service?

Tags: .net, windows, service

I have a windows service deployed, and since we have limited access to the server that it's running on, I'm wondering if it's possible that once the service is installed with installutil.exe, can we just stop the service, copy a new executable to the folder, and restart the service for the change to take effect, or does the service have to be uninstalled then reinstalled?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the new version will do. No need to reinstall the service.